# CSS first-child selector not working on most elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with the :first-child selector. I cant seem to get it working. The ideea of my code is to make a simple transform to two elements and for that i need to make use of the :first-child. There are 2 or more cases in my code that it doesn't work. Here they are:

The first case:

**CSS:**

```
.container_principal .continut.rand{
    display:none;
    sbackface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.container_principal .continut.rand:first-child{
    display:block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container_principal acasa">
    <div class="continut rand principal">Content goes here
    </div>

    <div class="continut rand produse">
    </div>

    <div class="continut rand despre">
    </div>

    <div class="continut rand servicii">
    </div>

    <div class="continut rand galerie">
    </div>

    <div class="continut rand contact">
    </div>
</div>
```

The second case (this involves jquery; the html for this css is the same as the one before)

**CSS**

```
.rotate{
transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.rotate:first-child{
display:none;
}

.rotate:last-child{
display:block;
}
```

**jQUERY:**

```
$(".col_1.produse").click(function(){
        $(".continut.rand.principal, .continut.rand.produse").addClass("rotate");
    });
```

If anyone is able to help me i'd be grateful. 
Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here is a Fidlle with all my code. Couldnt reproduce the problem any other way. 
http://jsfiddle.net/hn8Ye/4/

Comment: Where is `.col_1`? Specifically `.col_1.produse`

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: just a min . the .col_1 doesnt have anything to do with my problem:(. I'll put it if its needed.

Comment: Well I was only asking because that is in your jQuery bit.

Comment: And just as a side-note: remove the `s` character from the first of `sbackface-visibility`

Comment: may be not relevant to your problem but good to know that even IE 10 doesnt support preserve-3d

Comment: There has to be enough code here to reproduce the problem, otherwise there is no problem.

Comment: here is a fiddle. Seems like on fiddle it works just fine, but on my page it doesn't.http://jsfiddle.net/K2ZSa/

Comment: Added a fiddle with the full code. Doesn't seem to work. http://jsfiddle.net/hn8Ye/4/

Comment: Here is just the code from the first example: http://jsfiddle.net/hsMg7/ Only the first div is visible, which is what you intended, I suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps if your Fiddle and your posted code are the same.

`first-child` only matches the first element. The first child of the `.container_principal` is the `.header`, therefore `.container_principal .continut:first-child` will never match.

Try wrapping your `.continut` elements in another `<div>`

Comment: He can also use [first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)

Comment: @Itay Itai: What would that change? They are all `div`s.

Comment: @ItayItai What BoltClock said. `first-of-type` only refers to the node name, not the class. Which is a shame, because it'd be awesome if it could check for classes.